# Possibly necessarily P → Necessarily P?

Tags: modal-logic, ontological-argument

So I saw this proof for ◊□p → □p but I don't know if it's true.

> ◊~p → □◊~p (5 axiom)
> ◊~p → ~◊~◊~p (Definition of □)
> ~~◊~◊~p → ~◊~p (Contraposition)
> ◊~◊~p → ~◊~p (Double negation)
> ◊□p → □p (Definition of □)^2

In my mind this only gets me to

> □p → ◊□p

I only recently got exposed to modal logic but I understand the reasoning except the jump from step 2 to step 3.

> ◊~p → ~◊~◊~p (Definition of □)
> ~~◊~◊~p → ~◊~p (Contraposition)

Can someone clarify this for me? Is ◊□p → □p an accepted relationship?

Comment: The proof is correct, assuming of course that you have axiom 5. Contraposition is not specifically a rule of modal logic, it is just the familiar rule of propositional calculus that takes you from A → B to ¬B → ¬A.

Comment: I've been diving head first into this since posting. Is axiom 5 generally accepted?

Comment: It's just an axiom. You can use it or not depending on the interpretation of □. In S5, the frame condition on the accessibility of possible worlds is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. This seems to work well when understanding □ to mean 'it is necessarily true'. For other interpretations, you don't want axiom 5.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.